# Functors with two variables or more

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I'm kinda new to C++11 and I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) post about functors and It was very helpful, I just thought that is it possible to make a functor that receives more than a single variable?
for example we have the class below:

```
class my_functor{
public:
    my_functor(int a,int b):a(a),b(b){}

    int operator()(int y)
    {
        return a*y;
    }

private:
    int a,b;

};
```

Now I wonder is there any way that we could make a member function like

```
operator()(int y)
```

but with 2 or more (or unknown numbers!) of variables being received?

Comment: Sure, why not? The obvious approach should work, are you facing any particular problem when you try it?

Comment: `operator()` is just a funky function-name receiving however many arguments you write down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can pass as many arguments as you want to `operator()`.  See for example:

```
#include <iostream>
class my_functor{
public:
    my_functor(int a,int b):a(a),b(b){}

    int operator()(int y)
    {
        return a*y;
    }

    int operator()(int x, int y)
    {
        return a*x + b*y;
    }

private:
    int a,b;
};

int main()
{
    my_functor f{2,3};
    std::cout << f(4) << std::endl; // Output 2*4 = 8
    std::cout << f(5,6) << std::endl; // Output 2*5 + 6*3 = 28
    return 0;
}
```

To handle an unknown number of arguments, you need to look at the various solutions for handling variable number of arguments (basically, `#include <varargs.h>`, or template parameter packs).

Comment: wow thanks!!! I found out that I made a mistake and wrote my function header like "operator(,)(int x,int y)"