# pass more than single param to functor

Tags: c++

I did overload the operator() for my functor that now it receives two params.
I know it possible, but how I invoke it?
as far as I see, functions as std::transform or std::for_each iterate over single param
each time.

minimal example:

```
struct Functor
{
      Functor(double epsilon, double delta): ...
      float operator()(int a, int b) const;

      private:
      _epsilon, _delta;
}

Functor f(.1, .2);
std::vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // a should be taken from here each time
int b = 10;
std::vector k; // save result into k
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), b, k, f);
```

thank you!

edit: I do it because I want a to be taken each time from v,
whereas b will be constant

Comment: What would you expect `a` and `b` to be for each iteration of `transform`, assuming there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: let's say I have another vector u with another 4 nums for b

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the expected arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functors with two variables or more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451263/functors-with-two-variables-or-more)

Comment: Have you used `std::bind`?  Or better yet, a lambda?

Comment: Your intent is to have four invocations of `f(x, b)`, where `b` is constant and `a` takes its values from the elements of `v`? For each `x` in `v`, call `f(x, b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a standard algorithm to call a functor. You can use the function call operator and pass as many arguments as the functor expects:

```
Functor{.1, .2}(1, 2);
```

You've simply chosen two standard algorithms that use a unary functor as your examples. There are other standard algorithms that use functors of different arity. For example, `std::find` uses a binary functor such as the one in your example.

> I want ... b ... be constant

This is what functors are for. They can be composed. Here is an example of creating a unary functor from your binary one. I'll use a lambda:

```
auto unary = [](int a) {
    return Functor{.1, .2}(a, 2);
};
```

Comment: ah ty i see now. do you know a suitable algorithm if I want the first param to be taken from a vector whereas the second to be constant?

Comment: @NissimLevy you don't need another algorithm. See edit.

Comment: `std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(k), [](int a){return f(a, b);})`?